# access compare three tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to triple check that the data is consistent between the three tables and show if there are any discrepancies in any of the three tables?

Each table is not completely the same but they all have an `EmployeeID`, `amount`, `datepaid`, and `CID` column.

When I did with two tables I thought I had the SQL as:

```
SELECT tbMaster.EmployeeID, tbMaster.Amount, tbMaster.DatePaid, tbMaster.CID
FROM tbMaster LEFT JOIN tbCID ON (tbMaster.CID = tbCID.CID) AND (tbMaster.Amount = tbCID.Amount) AND (tbMaster.DatePaid = tbCID.DatePaid)
WHERE (((tbMaster.[Advance/paid])="Paid Respondent") AND ((tbCID.CID) Is Null));
```

It worked but if the `tbCID` had any discrepancies it did not catch it...

So for the three tables I thought:

```
SELECT tbMaster.EmployeeID, tbMaster.Amount, tbMaster.DatePaid, tbMaster.[Advance/paid], tbMaster.CID
FROM tbMaster, tbCID, table3
WHERE tbMaster.CID <> tbCID.CID
OR  table3.CID <> tbMaster.CID
OR  table3.CID <> tbCID.CID
OR tbMaster.Amount <> tbCID.Amount
OR  table3.AMOUNT <> tbMaster.AMOUNT
OR  table3.AMOUNT <> tbCID.AMOUNT
OR tbMaster.Datepaid <> tbCID.Datepaid
OR  table3.DATEPAID <> tbMaster.DATEPAID
OR  table3.DATEPAID <> tbCID.DATEPAID
```

But there is only 30 entries yet I get 5x or 6x copies and get over 30000 rows/entries in the query...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.  Also, if there are duplicates within a table for the columns you are interested in, then explain what to do about them.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. Could you add some screenshots and clarify your question?

Comment: Sorry Gordon and ibrahimozgon, I will be given 3 tables to try to triple check the data to ensure that they all have the same amount on the same date for the same person. If they do not they would like the ones that are dissimilar to show only.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a full cross join on your three tables, so for every combination of tbMaster row, tbCID row, and table3 row where the three don't match on the three columns, a row will be returned.

If you are trying to return a tbMaster row where the CID, Amount, and DatePaid do not appear in both tbSUID and table3, you need something similar to your first query:

```
SELECT tbMaster.EmployeeID, tbMaster.Amount, tbMaster.DatePaid, tbMaster.CID
FROM tbMaster 
LEFT JOIN tbSUID ON (tbMaster.CID = tbSUID.CID) AND (tbMaster.Amount = tbSUID.Amount) AND (tbMaster.DatePaid = tbSUID.DatePaid)
LEFT JOIN table3 ON (tbMaster.CID = table3.CID) AND (tbMaster.Amount = table3.Amount) AND (tbMaster.DatePaid = table3.DatePaid)
WHERE ((tbMaster.[Advance/paid])="Paid Respondent") 
AND ((tbCID.CID) Is Null) OR (table3.CID Is Null));
```

If the record has to appear in just one of tbSUID and table3, replace the last "OR" with "AND".

Comment: Don, THANK YOU! I got it!

`SELECT tbMaster.EmployeeID, tbMaster.Amount, tbMaster.DatePaid, tbMaster.[Advance/paid], tbMaster.CID
FROM (tbMaster LEFT JOIN tbCID ON (tbMaster.DatePaid = tbCID.DatePaid) AND (tbMaster.Amount = tbCID.Amount) AND (tbMaster.CID = tbCID.CID)) LEFT JOIN table3 ON (tbMaster.CID = table3.CID) AND (tbMaster.DatePaid = table3.DatePaid) AND (tbMaster.Amount = table3.Amount)
WHERE (((tbMaster.[Advance/paid])="Paid Respondent") AND ((tbCID.CID) Is Null)) OR (((tbMaster.[Advance/paid])="Paid Respondent") AND ((table3.CID) Is Null));`

Thank you!

Comment: MS Access SQL requires parentheses around multiple `JOIN` clauses as OP shows.

Comment: I realized that this query will only tell if there are paid respondent records in the master table that does not exist in table CID or table 3 but not the reverse nor does it check table CID against table 3...

Answer (score 0):

Consider subqueries in `NOT EXISTS` clauses:

```
SELECT m.EmployeeID, m.Amount, m.DatePaid, m.[Advance/paid], m.CID
FROM tbMaster m
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM tbCID c
   WHERE c.CID = m.CID OR c.AMOUNT = m.AMOUNT OR c.DATEPAID = m.DATEPAID)

OR NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM table3 t
   WHERE t.CID = m.CID OR t.AMOUNT = m.AMOUNT OR t.DATEPAID = m.DATEPAID)
```

---

For inverse comparisons, consider adding union queries with a *source_table* indicator:

```
SELECT m.EmployeeID, m.Amount, m.DatePaid, m.[Advance/paid], m.CID, 
       'tbMaster' AS [source_table]
FROM tbMaster m
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM tbCID c
   WHERE c.CID = m.CID OR c.AMOUNT = m.AMOUNT OR c.DATEPAID = m.DATEPAID)
OR NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM table3 t
   WHERE t.CID = m.CID OR t.AMOUNT = m.AMOUNT OR t.DATEPAID = m.DATEPAID)

UNION ALL

SELECT c.EmployeeID, c.Amount, c.DatePaid, c.[Advance/paid], c.CID, 
       'tbCID' AS [source_table]
FROM tbCID c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM tbMaster m
   WHERE m.CID = c.CID OR m.AMOUNT = c.AMOUNT OR m.DATEPAID = c.DATEPAID)
OR NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM table3 t
   WHERE t.CID = c.CID OR t.AMOUNT = c.AMOUNT OR t.DATEPAID = c.DATEPAID)

UNION ALL

SELECT t.EmployeeID, t.Amount, t.DatePaid, t.[Advance/paid], t.CID, 
       'table3' AS [source_table]
FROM table3 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM tbMaster m
   WHERE m.CID = t.CID OR m.AMOUNT = t.AMOUNT OR m.DATEPAID = t.DATEPAID)
OR NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM tbCID  c
   WHERE c.CID = t.CID OR c.AMOUNT = t.AMOUNT OR c.DATEPAID = t.DATEPAID)
```

Comment: Thank you this works as well as the one above! May I ask if there is a way to see if t.CID =c.CID... as well? i tried to add the inverse but it did not work

Comment: Add union queries for the inverse comparisons. See edit.